# Using a object which is not already persisted

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am working on a Spring-MVC project. In the project, I have 2 tables ProductBasic and ProductImage. The user should be able to upload upto 5 images in the ProductImage table. 
The ProductImage table has a foreign key reference to ProductBasic.

The problem : The user enters productinformation and uploads the productimages on the same JSP page. How can I save the productImages if ProductBasic is already not persisted?

I am pasting some code, Kindly have a look

ProductController :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductBasic productBasic,Model model){
        User user = userService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("product", new ProductBasic());
        productBasic.setProductimage(productprofileimage);
        productBasicService.addProduct(user,productBasic);
        productprofileimage =null;
        return "redirect:/product/show";
    }
```

The above method only adds one image and not in the ProductImage table, so it works.

ProductBasic model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductBasic {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "uploadinguser",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<ProductImage> productImageSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<ProductImage> getProductImageSet(){return this.productImageSet;}

    public void setProductImageSet(Set<ProductImage> productImageSet){this.productImageSet=productImageSet;}
}
```

ProductImage model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "productimages")
public class ProductImage {

 @Transient
    private List<MultipartFile> productImages;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private ProductBasic productimageupload;

    public ProductBasic getProductimageupload(){return this.productimageupload;}

    public void setProductimageupload(ProductBasic productimageupload){this.productimageupload=productimageupload;}

}
```

If any clarification is required, kindly let me know. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "uploadinguser",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

to this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "uploadinguser",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Using the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` will automatically cascade the persist and merge operations as well. So you can save the `ProductBasic` root entity and the images will be saved as well.

Just make sure you set both sides of the association too:

```
ProductBasic productBasic = ...;

ProductImage image1 = new ProductImage();
productBasic.getProductImageSet().add(image1);
image1.setProductimageupload(productBasic);

ProductImage image2 = new ProductImage();
productBasic.getProductImageSet().add(image2);
image2.setProductimageupload(productBasic);
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I just have one question, In the last code snippet, you have written, ProductBasic productbasic = ...; If I had the product information which is going to be persisted, then I can do the steps you have mentioned after that, but can you tell me how to get the product which is persisted, in short the code in ....  .Thank you. :-)

Comment: I think you get the ProductBasic from the Model already. Spring manages to map the request parameters to the current Model properties

Comment: ok, I will try and if I have problems I will comment here, sorry for late reply, I just came to office and checked.

Comment: So I used the save method of hibernate, which returns the id of the object which was saved and used that to save the new productImage with reference to ProductBasic.